# ASP.NET MVC ChildActionOnly Redirection

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm in the process of moving a web application over to ASP.Net MVC, using purely AJAX page requests rather than the current full-page request system.

One thing I would like to know is whether it is possible to automatically redirect a request marked with a `ChildActionOnly` attribute to the home page should the user navigate to it through the address bar?

As no pages can be navigated to directly via a URL, I want all URL's to be redirected back to the home page.

I had considered whether removing the default route configuration would prevent any kind of manual user navigation however I'm unsure if this would break anything else down the line.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, trying to hit a ChildActionOnly action from a URL throws an exception, and not a 404, but I could be wrong, it might be a 404.

Either way, there are tons of questions (with answers) on Stack Overflow on how to handle 404 and global exceptions, which you can use to redirect to the home page.

One word of caution though.  Be careful redirecting to the homepage when requests will be made via ajax.  Nothing worse than your homepage nested within an element that was supposed to load a partial.  The last time I worked on an MVC project, I had each action tagged wether or not it was an ajax action, so that we could return an "ajax" error page.

Answer (score 0):

When an action is marked as `ChildActionOnly`, it is removed from the route table for direct access. Therefore, to the routing framework, it appears as any other random URL that doesn't route to anything in your project, and you'd get a 404. If you want to redirect instead, then you should actually remove `ChildActionOnly` and then branch inside the action based on whether it was called in the context of a child action or not.

```
if (ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
{
    // do normal stuff
}
else
{
    return Redirect("/my/redirect/");
}
```

In other words, you expose it to the routing framework as a normal action, then if it's called directly, you redirect.